# get activity from my followers django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 3 models :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):    
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique =True)
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship',symmetrical=False,null=True, blank=True,related_name='related_to')

    def get_relationships(self, status):
        return self.relationships.filter(
        to_people__status=status, 
        to_people__from_person=self)

    def get_related_to(self, status):
        return self.related_to.filter(
        from_people__status=status, 
        from_people__to_person=self)

    def get_following(self):
        return self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

    def get_followers(self):
        return self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='from_people')
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='to_people')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)

class ActivityUser(models.Model):
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
   user = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
   userB = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='userFriend',null=True, blank=True)
   status = models.IntegerField(choices=NOTIFICATION_STATUS)
   date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Basically user can follow each other and users have activities. 
I would like to be able to get all the activity from all my followers and following.
Any idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about add another method to your UserProfile class?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique =True)
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship',symmetrical=False,null=True, blank=True,related_name='related_to')

    def get_relationships(self, status):
        return self.relationships.filter(
            to_people__status=status,
            to_people__from_person=self)

    def get_related_to(self, status):
        return self.related_to.filter(
            from_people__status=status,
            from_people__to_person=self)

    def get_following(self):
        return self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

    def get_followers(self):
        return self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)

    def get_all_activities(self):
        list_activities = []
        for follower in self.get_followers():
            list_activities.append(follower.ActivitieUser_set.all()        
        return list_activities
```

Comment: thank you, I posted my answer I think using a single query might be better

Answer (score 0):

Actually I used a single query

```
ActivityUser.objects.filter(
    Q(user__in=profile.get_followers()) | 
    Q(user__in=profile.get_following())).order_by("-date")
```